# Array.append changes previously added values - swift 4.0

Tags: arrays, swift

I am working on a project which should get data from different server URLs simultaneously using `GCD`. It is working as intended by getting data from servers and updating the view.

**Connection Controller:**

```
    private func initiateObjects() {
        self.stationCounter = 1
        self.request = StationRequests()
        self.object  = StationObject()
    }

    private func initiateRequests() {
        request = StationRequests(self.stationCounter)
        request.object = self.object
        request.delegate = self
    }

    private func sendRequest() {
        queueStation.async {
            self.request.SendRequest()
        }
    }

    private func updateView(_ obj: BaseObject?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {        
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .dataFetched, object: nil, userInfo: ["item": obj ?? BaseObject()])
        }
    }

    func managerDidReceived(data: Any, request: BaseRequest) {
        let parsedObj = request.object?.Parse(data)
        self.updateView(parsedObj)
    }
```

**View Controller:**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initiateStationListService()
    }

    private func initiateStationListService() {
        self.connection.initiate()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.dataFetched(_:)), name: .dataFetched, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func dataFetched(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let items = notification.userInfo as? [String:StationObject] else { return }
        guard let item = items["item"] else { return }
        self.stationList.append(item) //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
```

**The problem** is that when I want to append fetched object to my list to show in a `CollectionView`, the list items all change to the latest one. I mean, all previously added items get identical and same as the latest one. So, when I reload `CollectionView`, all records are same. The loaded item itself is correct and there is no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
self.stationList += [item]
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

Comment: It raises the error: `Argument type 'StationObject' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'`

Comment: what is `stationList`?

Comment: It is: `private var stationList = [StationObject]()`

Comment: Nothing has changed. Again, all items change to the latest one :(

Comment: It should work. Make sure your array is not updating from some other place.

Comment: How about accessing from other thread? I'm not sure, but maybe that's because I call it from `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172940/discussion-between-ivarun-and-hassan-shahbazi).

Comment: @ivarun While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks will take care of this next time. :)

Comment: @ivarun you can still [edit] your answer to take care of it this time as well :)